# How to use a select command to find all the records that has the maximum date value for a specific item?

Tags: sql, select

Say I have a table like this, we call it tbl_test

```
ID  thedate     actionid songid
1   2014-10-01  100      10
2   2014-09-30  100      10
3   2014-10-01  80       10
4   2014-09-30  80       10
5   2014-10-01  80       21
6   2014-09-30  100      21
```

Now I want to find all the record thats in the tbl_test where actionid=100 and with the latest [thedate] value. In this case, I want the final select result to be

(this is the result I want, not an existing table)
    ID  thedate     actionid songid
    1   2014-10-01  100      10
    6   2014-09-30  100      21

Question, how am I going to do that use nothing but a single select command in MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join to a query that returns the latest date for each song:

```
select tbl_test.*
from tbl_test
join (select songid, max(theDate) maxDate
      from tbl_test
      where actionId = 100
      group by songid) t on t.songId = tbl_test.songId and theDate = maxDate
where actionid = 100
```

This should perform pretty well as it makes only 2 passes over the table - one for the inner query that determines the latest date, and another to output the matching rows

Answer (score 0):

A general SQL way to get this is using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tbl_test t
where actionid = 100 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_test t2
                  where t2.songid = t.songid and t2.actionid = 100 and t2.thedate > t.thedate
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `songid, actionid, thedate`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for such a swift reply. But I'm still quite confusing about the solution you gave. What is t and t2? I only have one table called "tbl_test" and from that I want to use a single select command to filter out the final results

Comment: Those are table aliases for your table.  When I originally answered the question, you hadn't identified the name of the table.